# C# векторы решения показывают 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, вектор

Здраствуйте всем.

```
        public struct Vector3
        {
            public float x;
            public float y;
            public float z;
                public Vector3 Add(Vector3 other)
                {
                    Vector3 result = new Vector3();
                    {
                        x += other.x;
                        y += other.y;
                        z += other.z;
                    }
                    return result;
                    
                }
                public Vector3 Sub(Vector3 other)
                {
                    Vector3 result = new Vector3();
                    {
                        x -= other.x;
                        y -= other.y;
                        z -= other.z;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                public Vector3 Mul(float number)
                {
                    Vector3 result = new Vector3();
                    {
                        x *= number;
                        y *= number;
                        z *= number;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                public Vector3 Div(float number)
                {
                    Vector3 result = new Vector3();
                    {
                        x /= number;
                        y /= number;    
                        z /= number;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                public override string ToString()
                {
                    return "(" + x + "; " + y + "; " + z + ")";
                }
    
    
            
            
        }
```

В следующим cs файле в том же решении находится продолжение кода

```
    class Program1
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Vector3 up = new Vector3();
                up.y = 3;
                Vector3 forward = new Vector3();
                forward.z = 1;
    
                Console.WriteLine(up.Add(forward));
                Console.WriteLine(up.Sub(forward));
                Console.WriteLine(up.Mul(4f));
                Console.WriteLine(up.Div(2.5f));
            }
        }
```

Программа после сборки показывает решение, что векторы (0, 0, 0)
Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Ещё один вопрос как сделать проверку деления на ноль здесь же?

Comment: Вам вектор для чего, учебное задание или велосипед? Если учебное, то ответ ниже, если велосипед - то он уже есть https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3

Comment: Учебное задание